# Remove if else condition and convert the code into a functional way in scala

Tags: scala, if-statement

I have the below code in written in scala and i would like to convert into a functional way by removing if else statement.

```
case class Foo(val bar:String)

val foo : Option[Foo] = Some(Foo("mark"))

val bar = if (foo.isDefined) Some(foo.get.bar) else None
```

Can we try pattern matching in scala? need your guidance.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use pattern matching here.

```
val bar = foo.map(_.bar)
```

This should give you the expected result

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have one more scenario below, have to convert if else as a functional way in scala,  can you suggest.                                                                                                                 case class Foo(val bar:String)
val foo : Option[Foo] = Some(Foo("mark"))
val bar = if(foo.isEmpty) 123 else 234

Comment: `if(foo.isEmpty) 123 else 234` sounds like a very good way of expressing the condition. It's also absolutely functional by any reasonable definition. I would take that over using some library function any day. If the code you are trying to express is more complex than that you probably want to make the example more representative.

Comment: @Naveenkumar just for the sake of answering you could do `val bar = foo.fold(ifEmpty = 123)(_ => 234)` but in this case I would prefer the `if`. However, I would also say that not caring about the value inside the `Option` is weird _(yet not completely unheard of)_

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth noting that there's nothing "non-functional" about `if` *expressions*. Note that I didn't say "statement": an `if` *statement* needs to rely on side-effects to work. Languages like C and Java have `if` *statements* and have a *ternary operator* that allows to evaluate the condition as an expression, meaning it yields a result. This is *not* the case in Scala: the `if` is an expression and you actually took advantage of this in your code, assigning the result of the conditional to `bar`.

With that said, you can use pattern matching, but in this case I think you can use `map` to express the logic of the `if` above, as in the following example:

```
case class Foo(val bar:String)

val foo : Option[Foo] = Some(Foo("mark"))

val bar = foo.map(_.bar)

assert(bar == Some("mark"))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/P29Xu1n1Rw2rdL1RWmkopA/1).

Not surprisingly, notice the similarity between the definition of [`Option.map`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4b124f211b661d2ef280838cd7bfffb8277444d3/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L241-L242) and your code (basically equivalent, with the condition reversed and the possibility of applying a function, making it general enough for your case):

```
@inline final def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
  if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```

Comment: While I agree that `if` expression is functional, doing `isDefined` + `get` in `Option` is really bad idea.

Comment: I agree, but from the title and a further comment OP seems convinced that there's something about `if`s which makes code not functional. There are many cases where a simple `if` can be more direct and readable than abusing higher-order functions and one should not shy away from them because of a misunderstanding with regard to what "functional" means. With that said, I wouldn't recommend using `get` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the already given answers suggesting to use `.map(_.bar)` that if you do want to use pattern matching, it would look like the following:

```scala
val bar = foo match {
  case Some(f) => Some(f.bar)
  case None => None
}
```